# Unable to connect to the remote server ---> No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, asmx

I build a web service for my project . Recently I changed web service database connection to new database server . Can anyone tell me is it regarding firewall block . Cause I checked everything . Can anyone tell me any process to solve this issue . Thanks in advance .

Comment: Are you able to connect manually (e.g. using SQL Server Studio, or telnet)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not necessarily, it is responsible for firewall block.

1) Can you connect in this server using, management studio?
  In case yes, make sure that your port server is informed properly, sometime a typo happens.

In case not, you could validate if SQL Server service is running properly:

- In case running in container, make sure that your instance is running properly.
- In case traditional instance, make sure in windows service the SQL Server services (SQL Browser, or something like that) is running, it is a common issue.

If everything is ok, check if sql server port is running for another process. One way to figure it out is using telnet command

```
telnet <ipaddress> <sqlport(e.g. 1433)>
```